# "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, typeerror

There are some questions about this error, but I couldn't find any solutions on them. I'm developing a WordPress theme and during the enqueue script this error came up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at components.js?ver=4.8:65
    at components.js?ver=4.8:95
```

here is my enqueue code add to the functions.php:

```
function goc_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'goc-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'socicon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/socicon.css', array() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-social', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-social.css', array() );

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('simple-line-icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/simple-line-icons.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('cubeportfolio', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/cubeportfolio.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.fancybox.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'goc-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'goc-plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'goc-red3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/themes/red3.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'goc-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-jquery-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-jquery-migrate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-migrate.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(jquery), true); // prueba

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-reveal-animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/reveal-animate.js', array(), '4.8', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-reveal-animate-wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/reveal-animate/wow.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-cubeportfolio', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-counterup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-jquery.smooth-scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smooth-scroll/jquery.smooth-scroll.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider-for-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-slider.js', array(jquery), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-component', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/components.js', array(jquery), '4.8', false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-components', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/components-shop.js', array(), '4.8', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'goc-appjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array(), false, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'goc_scripts' );
```

and here is the code components.js where the error happens (line 65 and line 95):

```
var LayoutHeader = function () {
    var offset = parseInt($('.c-layout-header').attr('data-minimize-offset') > 0 ? parseInt($('.c-layout-header').attr('data-minimize-offset')) : 0);
    var _handleHeaderOnScroll = function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
            $("body").addClass("c-page-on-scroll");
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("c-page-on-scroll");
        }
    }

    var _handleTopbarCollapse = function () {
        $('.c-layout-header .c-topbar-toggler').on('click', function (e) {
            $('.c-layout-header-topbar-collapse').toggleClass("c-topbar-expanded");
        });
    }

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            if ($('body').hasClass('c-layout-header-fixed-non-minimized')) {
                return;
            }

            _handleHeaderOnScroll();
            _handleTopbarCollapse();

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                _handleHeaderOnScroll();
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Use `JQuery` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two solution for this:

***#1***

Repalce all `$` to `jQuery` in your code.

***#2***

Or a Simple way.

just assign `jQuery` to `$` as a `global variable` like following on the top of your `.js` file and all your code will work fine.

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hello @Jithin Raj P R - I replace the $ to JQuery in my components.js file (both ways) but nothing happens, the same error is keep on going, is driving me crazy. The same error :

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at components.js?ver=4.8:65
    at components.js?ver=4.8:95

Comment: @CapitanDuke can you share me a live link of your file so i can check.

Comment: You should clear your browser cache also and check that again. @CapitanDuke

Comment: @Jithin Raj P R Thanks !!! Yes probably was something with the cache that I kept seeing the bug ! :)